# lexical or preprocessor issue 'carboncore/macerrors.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm trying to build a OSX application(first since I've upgraded to XCode4), and I keep getting the error `lexical or preprocessor issue 'carboncore/macerrors.h' file not found`

I haven't done anything, I just created the project and ran it, getting this error. Any help getting that file back in?

Comment: Carbon's UI parts are more or less deprecated and I seem to recall that part of this deprecation is that these parts just aren't available to 64-bit application. Try making sure your build is set to use a 32-bit environment.

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Hm. In my scratchpad project, I can use the constants defined in `MacErrors.h` without including any header files. I'm guessing the file is not meant to be included explicitly and you can just nuke the `#include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the CoreServices framework to your project to make it build. CarbonCore is a sub-framework of CoreServices, and contains MacErrors.h.

Comment: That removes the MacErrors.h issue, but brings up 2 more, `Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error "_objc_retain", referenced from: -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o` and `Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error "_objc_release", referenced from: -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o` =/

Comment: You need to add the libraries that contain _objc_retain and _objc_release, then. I believe that's Foundation. But seeing that makes me wonder how you made this project in the first place? It sounds like it's not made from a template.